# Do you create gravitational waves by clapping your hands?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves, estimation, order-of-magnitude

I was thinking that given that GW's can be created by the merger of both black holes and neutron stars I don't see why any two colliding objects wouldn't also be able to create gravitational waves, such as two hands clapping. What do people think of this?

Comment: Yes, but they’d be very faint.

Comment: You create gravitational waves every time you walk, or every time your heart pumps, or almost any time anything moves.

Answer (score 4):

I once saw an estimate to the effect that if you spun a nuclear submarine around its short axis at $10^6$ rpm (corrected by Ben Crowell) you would radiate GW having a power equivalent to an ant walking up a hill.  So yes, but you get the idea.  That's why you need enormous mass acceleration to be able to see anything.  Just as knzhou says.

Comment: For your nuclear submarine, I get $(G/c^5)(mr^2)^2\omega^6\sim10^{-29}\ \text{W}$. For an ant crawling up a hill, I get $\sim10^{-6}\ \text{W}$. To get the sub's radiation up to ant-power levels, I have to make the frequency $10^6$ rpm.

Comment: This may be a bit off-topic, but any two particles interacting should produce gravitational waves.  Even though infinitesimally low energy, they should still carry spin.  Why don't we observe missing spin in those interactions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, hands clapping is physically comparable to an oscillating spring as shown here https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/ESSAYS/Boughn/boughn.html in Figure 1. The spring emits gravitational waves. Note that a time dependent mass quadrupole moment must exist for any system in order to emit gravitational waves. A counterexample would (theoretically) be a spherical symmetric supernova. In this case the mass quadrupole moment is zero. A 'real' supernova proceeds with some asymmetry though.